# Display png images on github pages

Tags: image, github, github-pages

I have an issue with github pages. The first image "logo.png" of my html page is not displaying.
Here is the error message in the console : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (). logo.PNG:1

My HTML code :

```
        <div class="logo">
      <a href="index.html"
        ><img
          class="header__logo"
          id="logo1"
          src="assets/pictures/logo.PNG"
          alt="FishEye Home page"
          tabindex="0"
        />
      </a>
    </div>
```

I tried following sources for my image :
assets/pictures/logo.PNG
assets/pictures/logo.png

It doesn't work.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

1. create a new issue on github repository.
2. copy and paste your image on new issue.
3. after it makes a url of you issue. Use it in your repository or ReadMe.md file.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear : my problem is not to create an issue but to display my image on github pages